# count of the multiple values in a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each keys have multiple values.
I am trying to count the total number of values.
For example:

```
key: 1, value: abc, bcd, egf
key: 2, value: asj,asfah,afhs,jhsafh
```

so, the total number of values are 3+4 = 7
What is the pythonic way to get this count.
Thanks

Comment: Good Q:  to answerers, what's gonna happen if len doesnt work in some items?

Comment: @yosukesabai I think the answers' assumption that the values are sequences is reasonable. The general solution for iterables would be `sum(1 for value in value_iterable)`, and there are several ways you could check if the item was iterable or not, if you could have a list that was that heterogeneous (you shouldn't).

Comment: @agf: Thanks, I often got screwed up like `dct['k'] = "wrong"`, instead of `dct['k'] = ["correct"]`.  guess it is a matter of discipline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
sum(len(val) for val in dictionary.itervalues())
```

Note that this uses a generator instead of creating a temporary list of lengths.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to iterate through all the keys and values in the dictionary, finding the length of each set of values.

The following does uses a list comprehension to build a list of all these lengths, and then takes their sum:

```
sum([len(value) for key, value in my_dict.iteritems()])
```

If you want to be more efficient, you can replace `for key, value in my_dict.iteritems()` with `for value in my_dict.itervalues()` and a use generator expression as suggested by Cameron.

Comment: Don't need the keys so `itervalues` is better than `iteritems` and don't need all the `len`s at once so a generator expression is better than a list comprehension.

Comment: Definitely the case. I would revise it, but Cameron definitely had a faster gun, so he can have the credit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're *sure* that each value in the dict will be a list, then this works:

```
sum(len(val) for val in d.itervalues())
```

If not, a bit more care is required, and probably a bit more info. Strings, for example, also have a `len` (the count of characters in the string). You probably want strings to count as 1 entry, rather than a count proportional to length.  If so, this less readable version works:

```
sum(1 if isinstance(val, basestring) else len(val) for val in d.itervalues())
```